# Problem with html2pdf using javascript rendering <h1> elements putting on wrong place

Tags: javascript, html, css, pdf, html2pdf

I've am working on this project and I want to make a **pdf export**. The problem is probably in scaling and I really need help.

Below are pictures from html and the **problem.** On the html picture you can see how organized it is and nicely looking but when **html2pdf renders it and sets its own scale it becomes unreadable and unogranized.**

**JS Function:**

```
     function pdf() {
      
       var element = document.getElementById('hello');
        var opt = {
          margin:       1,
          filename:     'myfile.pdf',
          image:        { type: 'jpeg', quality: 0.98 },
          html2canvas:  { scale: 2 },
          jsPDF:        { unit: 'in', format: 'letter', orientation: 'portrait' }
        }; html2pdf().set(opt).from(element).save(); }
```

**I need it in a4 format and that it doesnt create theese problems below:**

*****How html looks like:*****

[html site](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YFCd3.png)

***The occuring problems:***

["Pregdled" cant be seen from html site](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wfVKo.png)

What to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem.

**Explanation:**

When the html2pdf is rendering html site the best way to render is by **setting width as percentage (%)**

**for example:**

In my case 

## Pregled

 had **css width: 80vw;** so i changed it into **width: 100%;**

Hope someone finds this useful :)

Answer (score 0):

When styling an h1 in html2pdf with an addfont I get the error "TCPDF ERROR: Could not include font definition file: robotoslabbold".

The solution I found is use p instead.

Also, to add a font convert it using https://www.xml-convert.com/ttftopdf then upload all three files (z, afm, php) to wherever you want and reference in css.

$html2pdf->addFont('robotoslabbold', '', 'fonts/robotoslabbold.php');